# HTML Onclick event (Unexpected token })

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

i am currently having an issue with an onclick event i have racked my brains and unable to find the issue

index.html

```
<table  id="WIP" class="table" width="80%">
<tr><th colspan="6">Please Enter Your Parts In Progress</th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Station</th>
<th>Current WIP</th>
<th>Enter WIP</th>
<th>Save WIP</th>
</tr><tr>
<div id="10001DIV">
<th>Cutter</th>
<td># Of WIP</td>
<td><input name="10001WIP" type="text"></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="SaveWIP({div:document.getElementById("10001DIV").value,num:document.getElementById("10001WIP").value})">WIP</button></td>
</div>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
function SaveWIP(e) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("10001DIV").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q="+e.num+"",true);
  xhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try to replace `getElementById("10001DIV")` to `getElementById('10001DIV')` - single quotes

Comment: @LucasCosta - this produced the error ((index):17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick) in the console

Comment: For this, follow the @LGSon answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you only pass the `id`'s (and/or `name`'s) instead, and then, in your function use `querySelector('...').value`

If you add in `id` to your `input`, you can use `getElementById()`

*Side note, the `document.getElementById('10001DIV').value` won't work since that element is not an input, it is a `div`*

```js
function SaveWIP(e) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("10001DIV").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  
  xhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q="+document.querySelector('[name="'+e.num+'"]').value+"",true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<table  id="WIP" class="table" width="80%">
<tr><th colspan="6">Please Enter Your Parts In Progress</th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Station</th>
<th>Current WIP</th>
<th>Enter WIP</th>
<th>Save WIP</th>
</tr><tr>
<div id="10001DIV">
<th>Cutter</th>
<td># Of WIP</td>
<td><input id="10001WIP" type="text"></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="SaveWIP({div:'10001DIV',num:'10001WIP'})">WIP</button></td>
</div>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You still need to get the value of the input though: `document.getElementById(e.num).value`.

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: @RobG Yeah ... and I just saw we all made a mistake, as the input has no `id`, so I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the code in the click listener is not being interpreted correctly because there are unquoted double quotes inside double quotes. instead of:

```
onclick="SaveWIP({div:document.getElementById("10001DIV").value,num:document.getElementById("10001WIP").value})"
```

use single quotes inside the double quotes (saves quoting the internal doubles):

```
onclick="SaveWIP({div:document.getElementById('10001DIV').value,num:document.getElementById('10001WIP').value})"
```

#### Edit

You're also passing the *value* of the div, which is likely undefined, when you should just be passing the div, so:

```
onclick="SaveWIP({div:document.getElementById('10001DIV'),num:document.getElementById('10001WIP').value})"
```

Comment: I actually tried that first, though it didn't work ... did you test it?

Comment: Please explain "*didn't work*". Your initial question is about a parsing error, changing the quotes fixes that.

Comment: I'm not the OP, I posted an answer, where I first tried with changing the quotes, and that didn't work, then I removed the first object (which of course can't work as it is a div), but it still didn't work, as in _not getting the inputs value passed as an object value_

Comment: I see now that this will work if there will be and `id` on the input, so my bad saying this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in ID:

```
document.getElementById("10001DIV").value
```

What's that? Are you trying get value of DIV?
If you need get value of input, that has no ID, you can call it by NAME:

```
document.getElementsByName("10001DIV").value
```

Comment: Close. Only old IE confuses name and ID attribute values, and you're still trying to read the *value* property of a div. ;-)

Comment: And as `getElementsByName` returns an array of objects, it needs to be `document.getElementsByName("...")[0].value`